# Fill NAN values of a column in dataframe from other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
      main_id       p_id_y       score
1       1            123        0.617523
0       2            456        0.617523
0       3            789        NaN
0       4            987        NaN
1       5            654        NaN
```

also i have another dataframe df2.
which has the column's

```
p_id   score
 123    1.3
 456    4.6
 789    0.4
 987    1.1
 654    3.2
```

i have to fill all the scores for all `p_id_y which is NaN`  with the respective score of `p_id` in `df2`.

my final output should be.

```
      main_id       p_id_y       score
1       1            123        0.617523
0       2            456        0.617523
0       3            789        0.4
0       4            987        1.1
1       5            654        3.2
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?
i was thinking to use this

```
df['score'] = df['score'].fillna(something)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align data:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('p_id_y')
df1['score'] = df1['score'].combine_first(df2.set_index('p_id')['score'])
#df1['score'] = df1['score'].fillna(df2.set_index('p_id')['score'])

print (df1.reset_index())
   p_id_y  main_id     score
0     123        1  0.617523
1     456        2  0.617523
2     789        3  0.400000
3     987        4  1.100000
4     654        5  3.200000
```

Comment: won't combine first replace my all p_id_y score with the score from df2

Comment: I dont understand, can you explain more?

Comment: will combine_first replace only the score having NaN values? or replace all the score for that p_id_y

Comment: ir replace only `NaN`, it is alternative to fillna.

Comment: iam getting this error `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: It means in column `p_id_y` or `p_id` are duplicates. Can you check if in both columns are duplicates?

Comment: oh my bad in both the dataframe the column name is `p_id_y ` and not `p_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129968/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3):

use `fillna` and `join`

```
df.fillna(df[['p_id_y']].join(df2.set_index('p_id'), on='p_id_y'))
```

[image]